# Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ when parametrizing function with Num a

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have code like this

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (show func1)

x,y :: Num a => a
x = 1000
y = 1000

func1 :: String
func1 = func3  ++ "!"

func3 :: String
func3 = show (1 + sum' x y)

sum' :: Int -> Int -> Int
sum' a b = a+b
```

and I want to make `x` a parameter. So I figured I'd rewrite it like this:

```
func1 :: String
func1 = func3 x ++ "!"

func3 :: Num a => a -> String
func3 p = show (1 + sum' p y)
```

I'd expect this to be fine since I'm not modifying any constraints, but I get

```
file:21:27: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          func3 :: forall a. Num a => a -> String
        at file.hs:20:1-29
    • In the first argument of ‘sum'’, namely ‘p’
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘sum' p y’
      In the first argument of ‘show’, namely
        ‘(1 + sum' p y)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        p :: a (bound at file.hs:21:7)
        func3 :: a -> String (bound at file.hs:21:1)
   |
21 | func3 p = show (1 + sum' p y)
   |
```

I can solve this with  `x :: Int` and `func3 :: Int -> String`, but why do I have to? After all `a` might be an `Int` and there are no other calls expecting it to be anything other than an `Int`.

Comment: if `func3` ends up calling `sum'`, and `sum'` expects an `Int`, `func3` will have to take an `Int` as well...

Comment: `a` might be an `Int` but does not have to. Types won't prevent one to call `func3 (2.45 :: Dboule)` since the type of `func3` claims to be accepting all numeric types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion arises from how universal quantifiers work.

```
x :: Num a => a
x = 1000
```

This is a promise. It says "For any numerical type `a` you can give me, I can give you a value `x` of that type".

```
func3 :: Num a => a -> String
func3 p = ...
```

This is a different promise. It says "For any numerical type `a` you can give me, I can give you a function which takes `a` and returns a `String`". So `func3` must be able to act like a `Int -> String` or a `Double -> String` or any other numerical function, such as `Matrix -> String` or `Vector -> String`. So you can't assume the argument is an `Int`.

## The Easy Fix

`sum'` only uses `+`, so it should be able to take any numerical type as well. Simply change the arguments to `sum'` and your `func3` will start to work.

```
sum' :: Num a => a -> a -> a
sum' x y = x + y
```

Using the analogy above, the type signature here makes a promise: "If you give me any numerical type `a`, I can make a function which takes two `a`, adds them together, and returns an `a`".

This is *probably* the fix you want. 99% of the time, this is going to be the better solution. Alternatively, you could alter `func3` so that it only takes an `Int`, and then you'll have working (albeit less abstract) functions.

Sometimes, if you think a function can have a more general type but aren't sure, you can comment out the type signature and ask GHCi what the inferred signature is. Example GHCi usage:

```
> let sum' x y = x + y
> :t sum'
sum' :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So the interpreter gave you the most general type for `sum'`, which you can then put into your code to make it more general and abstract.

## The Long Answer

Let's take another look at your code.

```
y :: Num a => a
y = 1000

func3 :: Num a => a -> String
func3 p = show (1 + sum' p y)

sum' :: Int -> Int -> Int
sum' x y = x + y
```

Now, the signature `Num a => a -> String` associates like so: `Num a => (a -> String)`. Based on your comments, I believe you interpreted it as `(Num a => a) -> String`, which would mean "This function takes an argument which can be interpreted as any numerical type and returns a string". Now, this isn't actually valid Haskell code. However, if you're using GHC (which you likely are), you can enable a compiler extension `Rank2Types` to get this behavior.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

y :: Num a => a
y = 1000

func3 :: (forall a. Num a => a) -> String
func3 p = show (1 + sum' p y)

sum' :: Int -> Int -> Int
sum' x y = x + y
```

The `forall` at the beginning of the argument's type essentially says "Yes, I know that what I'm doing is not the usual Haskell interpretation, but do it anyway". Now `func3` is actually promising: "Give me an argument which can be interpreted as any numerical type `a` and I'll output a string". So when `func3` calls `sum'`, it can simply interpret that argument as an `Int`, like you originally intended.

This sort of code is non-idiomatic. `Rank2Types` (and its general form `RankNTypes`) is rarely needed in standard Haskell code. So unless you're doing something really fun with type theory, I suggest going with the short, easy approach. That being said, I wanted to include this just to show that the interpretation you were going for is actually possible, albeit with a compiler extension.